# sql query for extracting one column from many tables

Tags: sqlite

I need your support for a query in SQLite Studio.
I am dealing with a database made by 1,000 different tables.
Half of them (all named "news" + an identification number, like 04AD86) contain the column "category" which I am interested in. This column can have from 100 to 200 records for each table.
Could you suggest me a query that extracts "category" from every table and returns a list of all possible categories (without duplicates records)?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will probably need dynamic SQL to handle this in a single query.  If you don't mind doing this over several queries, then here is one option.  First do a query to obtain all the tables which contain the `category` column:

```
SELECT name
FROM sqlite_master
WHERE type = 'table' AND name LIKE 'news%'
```

Next, for the actual queries to obtain the unique categories, you can perform a series of unions to get your list.  Here is what it would look like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT category
FROM news04AD86
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT category
FROM news 05BG34
UNION
...
```

The `DISTINCT` keyword will remove duplicates *within* any given `name` table, and `UNION` will remove duplicates which might occur `between` one table and another.